# Different results: “xgboost” vs. “caret” in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, r-caret, xgboost

I try to setup a xgboost classification model in R

1. with the xgboost library
2. with caret

but I get different results (e.g. different predictions for the test dataset) despite I use the same settings(?).
I use the Ionosphere dataset from the mlbench library and try to keep it as simple as possible for this example (no cross validation, parameter tuning etc.):

Has someone an idea why I get different results (see below). Since caret is just a wrapper of xgboost ("it just calls the same xgboost package") the results should be exactly the same.

```
library(caret)
library(xgboost)
library(mlbench)

#####
###Load & Prepare Data
#####
data(Ionosphere)
dataset <- Ionosphere
dataset <- dataset[,-c(2)] #remove (Constant everywhere)
dataset$V1 <- as.numeric(as.character(dataset$V1)) #factor to numeric
dataset$Class<-ifelse(dataset$Class=="good",dataset$Class<-1,dataset$Class<-0) #convert good->1 and bad->0
dataset$Class<-as.factor(dataset$Class) #convert to factor

#####
###Create Train & Test Dataset
#####
set.seed(1992)
validation_index<-createDataPartition(dataset$Class, p=0.8, list=FALSE)
testSet<-dataset[-validation_index,]
trainSet<-dataset[validation_index,]

#xgb.DMatrix for xgb.train() ("trainSet[c(34)]=trainSet$Class")
xgb.trainData<-xgb.DMatrix(data = data.matrix(trainSet[,-c(34)]), label = data.matrix(trainSet$Class))
xgb.testData<-xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(testSet[,-c(34)]), label = as.matrix(data.matrix(testSet$Class)))

#####
###Set parameters & create models
#####
#params
param <-  data.frame(nrounds=c(100), max_depth = c(2),eta =c(0.3),gamma=c(0),
                    colsample_bytree=c(0.8),min_child_weight=c(1),subsample=c(1))                           

#xgboost
set.seed(1992)
fit.xgb <- xgb.train(
        params = list(eta = param$eta, max_depth = param$max_depth, 
            gamma = param$gamma, colsample_bytree = param$colsample_bytree, 
            min_child_weight = param$min_child_weight, subsample = param$subsample),    
        data = xgb.trainData, nrounds = param$nrounds, objective = "binary:logistic")

#caret
set.seed(1992)
fit.xgbTree <- train(Class~., data=trainSet, method="xgbTree",
                    metric="Accuracy", trControl=trainControl(method="none"),tuneGrid=param)

#####
###Print results (predictions)
#####
print("xgboost")
predictionxgb <- as.numeric(predict(fit.xgb,  xgb.testData) >= 0.5)
confusionMatrix(predictionxgb,testSet$Class)
#Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#
#          Reference
#Prediction  0  1
#         0 18  0
#         1  7 45
# ...


print("caret")
predictionsxgbTree <- predict(fit.xgbTree, testSet)
confusionMatrix(predictionsxgbTree, testSet$Class)
#Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#
#          Reference
#Prediction  0  1
#         0 17  0
#         1  8 45
# ...
```

This information about the models may help too (I dont see an important difference):

```
#xgboost:
fit.xgb
##### xgb.Booster
#raw: 35.9 Kb 
#call:
#  xgb.train(params = list(eta = param$eta, max_depth = param$max_depth, 
#    gamma = param$gamma, colsample_bytree = param$colsample_bytree, 
#    min_child_weight = param$min_child_weight, subsample = param$subsample), 
#    data = xgb.trainData, nrounds = param$nrounds, objective = "binary:logistic")
#params (as set within xgb.train):
#  eta = "0.3", max_depth = "2", gamma = "0", colsample_bytree = "0.8", min_child_weight = "1", subsample = "1", objective = "binary:logistic", silent = "1"
#xgb.attributes:
#  niter
#callbacks:
#  cb.print.evaluation(period = print_every_n)
#niter: 100


#caret:
fit.xgbTree$finalModel
##### xgb.Booster
#raw: 36 Kb 
#call:
#  xgboost::xgb.train(params = list(eta = param$eta, max_depth = param$max_depth, 
#   gamma = param$gamma, colsample_bytree = param$colsample_bytree, 
#   min_child_weight = param$min_child_weight, subsample = param$subsample), 
#    data = x, nrounds = param$nrounds, objective = "binary:logistic")
#params (as set within xgb.train):
#  eta = "0.3", max_depth = "2", gamma = "0", colsample_bytree = "0.8", min_child_weight = "1", subsample = "1", objective = "binary:logistic", silent = "1"
#xgb.attributes:
#  niter
#callbacks:
#  cb.print.evaluation(period = print_every_n)
#niter: 100
#xNames: #V1V3V4V5V6V7V8V9V10V11V12V13V14V15V16V17V18V19V20V21V22V23V24V25V26V27V28V29V30V31V32V33V34
#problemType: Classification
#tuneValue:
#          nrounds max_depth eta gamma colsample_bytree min_child_weight subsample
#1     100         2 0.3     0              0.8                1         1
#obsLevels: 01
#param:
#        list()
```

Comment: Maybe could be due to the differences in the default parameters used by both `caret` and `xgboost`.

Comment: I think I found the problem: Its the "colsample_bytree=c(0.8)" value ("subsample ratio of columns when constructing each tree"). The subsample created when using caret must be different to the subsample created by xgboost (despite I set the seed to "1992" before running each code).  If I set this value to 1 (no subsampling) I get the same results (even if I change other values (e.g. eta, nrounds etc.). The same problem occur with subsample values !=1.

Comment: Ok, one last thing. If you set the seed in the training control ("trainControl(method="none",seeds=1992)") in the caret variant you get the same results as in the xg.boost case - even for "colsample_bytree!=1" and "subsample!=1".  So this should answer the whole question!

Comment: Good to know, because I had some issues `seed` too.